# Mongoose - `strict` option not working in findOneAndReplace

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to implement PUT and PATCH request using Mongoose,the code for handing both requests are as follows:

```
function colCon(){
    /* ... retrieve mongoose model ... */
}

function putData(_title = '', newData = {}){
    console.log('> put data');

    const condition = {title : _title};
    return colCon().then(async model => {
        return model.findOneAndReplace(
            condition, 
            newData,
            {
                returnDocument : 'after',
                strict : false
            }
        ).then(doc => {
            return doc;
        }).catch(err => {
            throw err;
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        throw err;
    })
}

function patchData(_title = '', newData = {}){
    console.log('> patch data');

    const condition = {title : _title};
    return colCon().then(async model => {
        return model.findOneAndUpdate(
            condition, 
            newData,
            {
                returnDocument : 'after',
                strict: false
            }
        ).then(doc => {
            return doc;
        }).catch(err => {
            throw err;
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        throw err;
    })
}
```

While both have similar approaches (retrieve model -> find and update / replace -> show after-modified result), the results are quite different. For example this is my intial schema and document

```
//schema
{
    title: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
    },
    
    content: { 
        type: String,  
    }
}

//document sample 
{
    "content": "Something here",
    "title": "Some title"
}
```

And this is the result after I update / replace with the same new data

```
//new data
{
    "content": "Something new here",
    "title": "Some title"
    "car": "bugati"
}

//PATCH result
{
    "content": "Something new here",
    "title": "Some title",
    "car": "bugati"
}

//PUT result
{
    "content": "Something new here",
    "title": "Some title"
}
```

Although I have turn off `strict` mode in both functions, extra fields is still prevented in PUT request.

How can I disable it in PUT function the same as PATCH?

Thank you in advance!